# Exporting .org files to LaTeX - Error

Tags: pdftex, emacs, auctex, org-mode

I'm new to EMACS (on Ubuntu) and I have started using the `org` mode to begin with. I tried to convert my .org files into LaTeX only to see an error saying `pdf was not produced`
Upon checking the error online, I understood that packages required for .org to latex were not available. I used `sudo apt-get install auctex` to install the required packages. Now I'm left with the following error message.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(/home/prasannarajaram/list.tex
LaTeX2e 
Babel  and hyphenation patterns for 2 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def)
kpathsea: Running mktextfm ecrm1095
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1095
This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)

kpathsea: Running mktexmf ecrm1095

! I can't find file `ecrm1095'.
 ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1095

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
 ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1095

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: ecrm1095.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1095' failed to make ecrm1095.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font T1/cmr/m/n/10.95=ecrm1095 at 10.95pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not
 found.
 
                   relax 
l.100 \fontencoding\encodingdefault\selectfont

) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fixltx2e.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty))))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty)

! LaTeX Error: File `wrapfig.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or  to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
 

l.10 \usepackage
                {soul}^^M
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on /home/prasannarajaram//list.log.
```

Where am I going wrong? Do I need to install more packages? or is it to do with the configuration.

Note: I'm pressed up for download limits. Already used up 400+ MB for downloading `AUCTEX`

The source `org` file is here

```
This is my first to do list in ORG mode in emacs

* This is heading level 1
  There should be some text here
** Heading level 2
This is to see how the system behaves when there is text between level 1 and 2
*** this is heading level 3
THIS also Speaks VOLUMES about THE POWER OF EMACS-ORG MODE. 
**** This is heading level 4
*this text will be bold*

/whereas this will be italics/

_and this needs to be underline_

I WOULD LIKE TO SEE IF IT INDENTS BELOW THE THIRD HEADING. 

However the C code for printing Hello World program will look like this

#+begin_SRC C
#include 
int main (void) 
{ 
printf("Hello World!"); 
return 0; 
}
#+end_SRC C 

#+begin_quote
"This is a quote"
#+end_quote

* Let me create a list here [66%] 

- [X] first item
- [ ] second item
- [X] third item
  - [X] is this a nested item
  - [X] is this also nested - i doubt - yes it is

  First I would like to list down the list of commands for Org mode I have learnt so far.

- An asterisk creates a heading level 1
  + A double asterisk creates a heading level 2 and so on so forth
  + To create a check list use `-[ ]` 
  + In order to see the percentage of the items checked off in the check list use `[0%]`
  + In order to see the number of checked items checked off in the check list use `[0/0]`
- this is another one
- this is the next one 
  + this is an unordered list


* TODO list [4/6] : 
- [ ] How to create a numbered list
- [ ] How to markup multiple lines of code in =code= style
- [ ] How to create a bulleted list
- [X] How to split screens in EMACS - for horizontal split use C-x-2; vertical split:C-x-3
- [X] How to toggle a check list item - C-c C-c
- [X] In order to change the outline view to a cleaner view use the command M-x-org-indent-mode
- [X] In order to wrap the text to be visually pleasing use M-x-visual-line-mode


* Let us try to make a table now
| S.No  | Name       |
|-------+------------|
|    |            |
| 1     | Arthy      |
| 2     | Indu       |
| 3     | Padmavathy |
| 4     | Prakruti   |
| 5     | Prasanna   |
| 6     | Rajaram    |
|-------+------------|
| Total |            |

** More details
| S.No | Work location        | Working hours | Price |
|------+----------------------+---------------+-------|
|   |                      |            |       |
| 1    | United States        | X-Y           |   100 |
|------+----------------------+---------------+-------|
| 2    | United Arab Emirates | X'-Y'         |   100 |
|------+----------------------+---------------+-------|


* Conclusion
#this is a COMMENT AND I HOPE this will not be displayed

** COMMENT and this will not be displayed


* Links
[[http://www.google.com][Google.com]]

 #+BEGIN_VERSE
      Great clouds overhead
      Tiny black birds rise and fall
      Snow covers Emacs

          -- AlexSchroeder
 #+END_VERSE
```

Comment: You have not installed all packages. `wrapfig.sty` is (apparently) in the Apt package `texlive-latex-extra`. The font might be in either `texlive-fonts-extra` or `texlive-fonts-recommended. Can you post the `.org` file (if fairly minimal)?

Comment: Also, if `400 MB` is pressing your limits, you may want to consider eliminating the `docs` from you TeX Live installation (which I don't normally recommend!!).  Really, though, if 0.5 GB is a problem, your system is very small! Is this a dual Ubuntu/<something else> install?

Comment: @jon it is not the system capacity. It is the download limit. If I'm going to go over 1GB of download, I should consider upgrading my connection to unlimited download type to save myself from extra cost. BTW, I have updated the question with ORG source

Comment: @jon I tried `sudo apt-get install wrapfig.sty` but it didn't work? Can you please let me know where I can the right installation / configuration procedure?

Comment: I didn't say install wrapfig, I said it is in the Apt package `texlive-latex-extra`, so you should install that (`sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra`). Or, if download limits are an issue, get the package from [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig?lang=en) and install to `~/texmf/tex/latex/wrapfig` -- but then you run the risk of 'dependency hell'.

Comment: "dependency hell" - I like this word already..... Another 558 MB. I upgraded my download limit already. Thanks for the valuable tip @jon

Comment: @Prasanna Do a custom install and miss out the documentation and sources

Comment: Note that `soul.sty` is also in `texlive-latex-extra`. (A good simple, but not 100% perfect check is to do, e.g., `apt-cache search soul`.)

Comment: @jon `sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra` did not solve the problem. The following errors still exists `kpathsea: Running mktexmf ecrm1095!   I can't find file `ecrm1095'.
<*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1095
                                                  
Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1095 `

Comment: As I explained, the **font** is likely in one of the texlive font packages (see first comment). I should have been more explicit since I think you are new to LaTeX. However, if you prefer to not install new fonts, you should export the `.org` file to `.tex` (do not go straight to PDF) and modify the exported file before compiling.

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly an Ubuntu answer, but I came to this page looking for a solution for the same error on a Mac. I believe my MacOS-specific answer can be adapted to other OSes.

For me, installing the `wrapfig` (and a few more) packages did the trick:

```
cd /Library/TeX/texbin
sudo tlmgr update --self
sudo tlmgr install wrapfig
sudo tlmgr install marvosym
sudo tlmgr install wasysym
```

After that I was able to export to latex/PDF successfully.

**Update 2022:**
This time around my org export included something that required me to also do:

```
sudo tlmgr install capt-of
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using a really old TexLive. It is not your fault, Ubuntu has always been way behind regarding LaTeX. Update your TexLive installation to a more current version, not using Ubuntu, using these instructions [Installing TeX Live over the Internet](http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) and I think your problems will be history.

Comment: Note that if you uninstall TeXLive bundled with Ubuntu, it will complain about unresolved dependencies.  To get around that, you should install a [dummy package](https://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html).

Comment: I have always had problems with TeXLive\Ubuntu, and it is usually years out of date.  I don't even bother with it anymore, I just install it over the web and use tlmgr to update it.  Thanks for the tip on using a dummy package.

Comment: just a comment to those here in 2024 : its still  a confusing mess ;) it's not just you.

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread by having the same error message:

`! LaTeX Error: File wrapfig.sty not found.` on manjaro.

`sudo pacman -S texlive-latex-extra` fixed it for me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!